# How can I update users FCM token if their current one no longer works?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I discovered an issue with my application, certain users stopped receiving push notifications for awhile. Their FCM token that is associated with their account seems to either have expired or they need a new one. I tested by deleting the app on my device and I was issued a new fcm token in Xcode.

I copied that FCM token from the Xcode console and manually replaced it with the one I had in Firebase database, I then was able to successfully receive push notifications.

My question, is it possible to renew current users FCM token when they sign back into/ or open the app again so they can receive push notifications successfully?

Here is my app delegate

```swift
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: application)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return true
    }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Registered for notifications", deviceToken)
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    }



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Registered with FCM with token:", fcmToken)
    }

    // Listen for user notifcations
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }


    private func attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        print("Attempting to register APNS...")

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self


        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, . badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to request auth:", error)
                return
            }

            if granted {
                print("Auth granted.")
            } else {
                print("Auth denied")
            }

        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the Firebase Messaging delegate `FIRMessagingDelegate` to handle updates to the FCM token. Ideally, you want to handle this on app launch, so consider doing this in the App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        return true

    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid { // user is signed in

            Firestore.firestore().collection("userProfiles").document(userId).updateData(["fcmToken": fcmToken]) { (error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I already have FIRMessageingDelegate, it was in ```private func attemptRegisterForNotifications``` however I moved it to ```didFinishLaunchingWithOptions``` When I open the app or create a new account, the Xcode console tells me FCM token for the device and it is also sent to the ```user``` node in the database. If I uninstall the app and run it again, Xcode console  provides me with a different FCM token but the database does not update and keeps the old one. Then push notifications are not received..

Comment: This delegate method is called every time the user launches the app. Therefore, simply write to the database inside it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Opps sorry I just saw your updated answer after my first comment

Comment: I am using ```realtime-database``` would this still be similar?

Comment: It is your responsibility to manually update the database with the FCM token, that's why.

Comment: Would you mind moving to a quick chat so I don't flood this comment section?

Comment: I don't remember the syntax for RTDB writes but yes the concept is entirely the same. Just write this FCM token to the user in RTDB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206752/discussion-between-bsod-and-clint).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to manually "renew" a device token (in fact, there's no way to force that).  Instead, you should expect that the device token can change at any time.  Because your app might unexpectedly get a new token, you should record that token for the user every time your app launches.  The old token will no longer work, and your server code should check for failure in order to know when it's time to remove it.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Do you mind pointing me in the right direction on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The answer is telling you what you need to do.  If you're having problems with implementation, please ask a new question that includes your code, and explain how it's not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your users token in your servers database in every app launch, so you always have the latest token.

Comment: I've been doing research but the docs are a little confusing when it comes to FCM. I've been trying to find source code on how to implement a function that updates user tokens.